# TS compiler doesn't recognize imported class

Tags: typescript, webpack

When running the web app and clicking my "Start" button, I get a `console.error` error that tells me `Uncaught ReferenceError: Player is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>`. This error transforms into `Uncaught ReferenceError:Player is not defined` if I try instantiating the `Player` class outside the scope of my event listener.

`Player` is the only class with this issue.

```js
//app.ts
/// <reference path="game.ts" />
/// <reference path="player.ts" />
document.getElementById('startGame')!.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        const player:Player= new Player();
        player.name=Utility.getInputValue('playername');




//player.ts
class Player implements Person{
    name!:string;
    age?:number;
    highScore!:number;
}



//utility.ts
class Utility{
    static getInputValue(elementId:string):string{
        let inputElement:HTMLInputElement=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(elementId));
        return inputElement.value;
    }
```

webpack config:

```
const path=require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './js/app.js',
  devServer: {
    inline: false
  }
};
```

Comment: If you are already using webpack, why are you using `reference` instead of `import` statements?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm following a pluralsight tutorial. If there's any more info needed to figure out what's going on, I'm ready to provide.

Comment: This also might help: [In TypeScript, when to use reference, when to use import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121354/in-typescript-when-to-use-reference-when-to-use-import?rq=1) (one of the keys here is that `reference` only helps with types, not with actually including the code for usage)

Comment: @crashmstr `import` needs to be used in conjunction with `export`, if I'm not mistaken. Using export on the class generates an error on `Player`.

Comment: How is webpack set up? Normally, you use `import` statements (with corresponding `export`s) and webpack figures out how to compile everything into one or more JavaScript files. Without that, you would need to use `script` tags in your html to make sure all appropriate JavaScript files are included so the definitions are available.

Comment: So you might need to include your html file and your webpack config.

Comment: @crashmstr added my webpack config, not sure what the relevant part of the html file might be.

Comment: Since it looks like you are actually compiling with `tsc`, my guess is that you do not have `script` includes for all of the js files generated. Everything needs to be loaded into the browser (typical usage of webpack *compiles* and *bundles* the code with "loader" modules).

Answer (score 0):

Edited my tsconfig with these options and it worked:

```
{
    "compilerOptions":{
        "outFile": "../js/app.js"
    },
"files": [
    "./app.ts"
]
}
```

Apparently, using the triple slash directive `/// <reference path="..." />` requires `outFile` and `files` to be configured.